# Display inner element when hovering over an outer element

Tags: html, css

I have a really simple example below of what I am trying to do, [and a fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/yWZ33/2/)

```
<html>

<head>

<style>
#testDiv{
    display:block;
}

#hiddenDiv{
    display:none;
}

#testDiv:hover + #hiddenDiv{
    display:block;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="testDiv">

    <h1>Hello World</h1>

    <div id="hiddenDiv">
        <h2>Hidden normally</h2>
    </div>

</div>



</body>

</html>
```

Basically, when I hover over the **#testDiv**, I want to display **#hiddenDiv**. I need to put the div I wish to display inside **#testDiv** or else it won't be accessible when I move the mouse onto it.

Is this possible with CSS, or will I need to use Javascript?

Comment: What part of what you have doesn't work? Just `#testDiv` not changing on hover?

Comment: I want to change the display type of `#hiddenDiv` when I hover over `#testDiv`, while keeping `#testDiv` as it was before

Comment: I don't see anything in your example that would change testDiv's display. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ks7YK/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This CSS from your example:

```
#testDiv:hover + #hiddenDiv{
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

is saying:

> any time #testDiv is hovered, set any sibling #hiddenDivs to font-weight: bold;

The `+` means sibling. It works in your second example because `#hiddenDiv2` is a sibling of `#testDiv2`.

When the target items are nested the CSS selector changes to a child selector. This:

```
#testDiv:hover #hiddenDiv {
    display:block;
}
```

is saying:

> any time #testDiv is hovered, set all child #hiddenDivs to display: block;

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the display changing in Google Chrome, but in case you have something else changing it in your scenario, you could try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/RDBf9/

What I did was add another style only for the `testDiv` hover

```
#testDiv:hover{
    display:list-item;
}
```

#### Update

In your updated scenario, `testDiv` became a parent ( congratulations! ) of `hiddenDiv`.

So you need to select the `hiddenDiv` that has a hovered parent with id `testDiv`, like this:

```
#testDiv:hover #hiddenDiv{
    display:block;
}
```

P.S: In CSS, selectors are readed from right to left. That is the order browsers read them too.

Comment: I've updated the question with my actual problem, thanks